# How to connect into firebird's docker image, using a docker filepath?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, firebird2.5

I have a firebird DB image running on port 3050, I need to access a file inside that image via url, so I can create a firebird connection (Yes firebird demands a filepath), but I can't find the file using the url
Is there a way to expose a file inside the docker, and make it accessible via url?  example localhost:3050/databases/test.fdb   << I need to connect to this via dbeaver

[its runnning normally on the 3050](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ4ny.png)

[heres the file I need to access via url (thats inside the container)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q87vz.png)  (located on /databases)

[How I'm trying to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow1LZ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the absolute path `/databases/DREAMCLUB.FDB`, not the relative path `databases/DREAMCLUB.FDB`. See also the [Jaybird FAQ on JDBC URLs](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/faq.html#pure-java-default) (Jaybird is the Firebird JDBC driver used by DBeaver):

> On Linux the root `/` should be included in the path. A database
> located on `/opt/firebird/db.fdb` should use (note the double slash
> after port!):
>
> ```
> jdbc:firebirdsql://host:port//opt/firebird/db.fdb
> ```

And a similar mention in the [Jaybird JDBC Driver Java Programmer's Manual](https://firebirdsql.github.io/jaybird-manual/jaybird_manual.html#connection-drivermanager):

> On Unix platforms the path must include the root, as the path is
> otherwise interpreted relative to a server-dependent folder. Having to
> include the root has the effect that a database in
> `/var/firebird/employee.fdb` needs to use a double `//` after the host
> name (and port) in the connection string:
> `jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost//var/firebird/employee.fdb`

As an aside, Firebird doesn't require you use a file path, you can also define an alias in `aliases.conf` (Firebird 2.5 and earlier) or `databases.conf` (Firebird 3.0 and higher).

Comment: Thank you, using "//" solved the problem haha.